# Signification de « petite famille » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

Une « petite famille » est composée de quels membres ? Peut-on par exemple dire d'un couple qu'il forme une petite famille ?

Voici un exemple d'emploi (proposé dans le [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26591/signification-de-petite-famille#comment54134_26591) de Kerkyra) :

> Tu passeras le bonjour de ma part à ta petite famille !

Comment: Cette question serait pareille dans n'importe quelle langue....Ce  n'est pas  une question sur le "français".

Comment: Dans quel contexte as-tu rencontré cette expression ? On emploie parfois "petite famille" comme un diminutif un peu familier et affectueux, par exemple "tu passeras le bonjour de ma part à ta petite famille !". Dans ce cas-là, il n'y a pas de sens particulier à part la connotation amicale, les personnes désignées sont les mêmes que si on avait uniquement dit "famille".

Comment: @Lambie Je ne pense pas qu'on dit en anglais: say hello to your small family! Par contre, on dit bien passe le bonjour à ta petite famille comme dans l'exemple donné par Keryra.

Comment: @Kerkyra, le contexte, c'est que j'ai voulu l'utiliser, je sais que ça se dit, quand on parle de sa famille mais en réfléchissant je me suis posé la question sur quand on pourra l'utiliser ou pas suivant si on veut inclure les ascendants ou pas ou si la famille n'est formée que par un couple, etc.

Comment: @MedNait Ah bon? Maintenant tu viens nous dire: Dis bonjour à ta petite famille? Comment aurait-on pu savoir cela? Hein? Voilà le contexte manquant. On ne dirait en aucun cas little family. Par contre, a little family existe dans  plusieurs contextes. Il faut toujours donner son contexte. Say hello to your sweet or nice or nice little or sweet little family. Dans ce contexte. Petite famille est ce qu'on appelle a term of endearment, comme le filme: Term of Endearment.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de la taille d'une famille. Petite ici veut dire: ta famille sympa. C'est  une famille dont les membres sont proches les uns des autres.

Comment: @Lambie Vous avez raison, le contexte manque. J'ai écris la question vite fait en étant pressé. Merci pour les commentaires

Comment: @MedNait Merci de l'avoir dit. J'en suis reconnaissante.

Comment: @Agent Baptiste, merci pour l'édition, ça met vraiment en valeur la question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans cette expression, le « petit » est un peu superflu. Il sert en fait à ajouter une espèce de nuance [hypocoristique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocoristique) à ce groupe nominal.

*Famille*, ici, désigne généralement la **famille nucléaire**, soit un couple (ou, j'imagine, un parent célibataire) et ses enfants, par opposition à la *maisonnée* (qui peut inclure divers parents additionnels) et à la *famille élargie* (dont l'étendue peut varier considérablement d'une famille à l'autre selon le nombres de génération que l'on remonte pour la définir).

Comment: It's a term of endearment and has nothing to do with size.

Comment: Et peut-on parler de petite famille pour désigner juste un couple sans enfants !

Comment: Aucune idée. Moi, je dirais dans ce cas-là: Dis bonjour à ta petite femme. Quoique ça fait un peu prolo et c'est pour les hommes seulement de parler comme ça.

Comment: @Lambie Ok. C'était un peu cette réflexion qui m'a poussé à poser la question. Maintenant c'est plus clair :-)

Comment: @NedNait En pensant bien, on dirait: And say hello to that nice family of yours! En partant.

Answer (score 4):

Un couple marié, si l'on sait qu'il est sans enfant, n'est pas une famille dans le langage courant, bien qu'il en soit une techniquement et donc dans le langage administratif. Par exemple si un formulaire demande le nom du chef de famille, celui d'un des deux membres du couple convient ; on peut parler de "regroupement familial" dans le cadre d'une procédure visant à permettre l'immigration d'un conjoint ; mais on ne dirait pas "j'ai passé les vacances en famille" pour dire en couple, ni "comment va la famille ?" pour demander des nouvelles du conjoint.

"Petite famille" au sens propre peut signifier une famille avec un petit nombre d'enfants. À chacun ses références en la matière... Notons qu'en France, il existe des tarifs réduits dans les transports en commun attribués aux familles dites "nombreuses", ce qui signifie ayant 3 enfants ou plus. On peut donc considérer qu'à partir de 3, au moins pour certaines personnes, une famille cesse d'être petite et devient nombreuse !

Au figuré, "petite famille" est une locution affectueuse qui se réfère à la famille immédiate de la personne, incluant le conjoint et les enfants, par exemple dans "comment va la petite famille ?" ou "tu passeras le bonjour à la petite famille".

Cette locution peut être utilisée aussi pour clarifier qu'il ne s'agit pas d'autres membres de la famille, par exemple "passer les vacances en famille" peut vouloir dire avec les frères et sœurs, avec les parents, avec les cousins, avec les grands-parents... Tandis que "passer les vacances avec la petite famille" signifie avec le conjoint et les enfants.

Si l'on sait déjà que quelqu'un n'a pas d'enfants, on préférera "passe le bonjour à ton mari / à ta femme" plutôt que "passe le bonjour à la petite famille", qui sous-entend la présence d'enfants.

Comment: Donc, en gros, dès qu'il y a un couple avec un enfant ou plus on peut bien utiliser l'expression, sinon à éviter !

Comment: En effet. Ça peut à la limite s'utiliser si on ne sait pas si l'autre personne a des enfants ou non mais c'est tout de même un peu maladroit.